# Copy files to sub-directories

Tags: javascript, gulp

Using gulp, is there any easy way to copy each file that matches some glob to a sub-directory relative to the original file's location?

For example:

The source glob might look like this:

```
'./**/*.txt'
```

This is what the file structure might look like beforehand:

```
./dir1/file1.txt
./dir2/file2.txt
./dir3/file3.txt
```

This is what the corresponding file structure would look like afterward:

```
./dir1/file1.txt
./dir1/sub/file1.txt
./dir2/file2.txt
./dir2/sub/file2.txt
./dir3/file3.txt
./dir3/sub/file3.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure whether native gulp provides any way of doing this. But it looks like one way of doing this would be to use the [gulp-rename](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-rename) package.

```
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.src('./**/*.txt')
    .pipe(rename(function (path) {
        path.dirname += '/sub';
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
```